# How to get myself recognised on a new Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, openid, linked-accounts

I have an account on Stack Overflow and Server Fault etc, probably logging in via Google OpenId. Stack Overflow does a good job of remembering who I am.

Today, I want to ask a question on crypto.stackexchange.com, but I must log in first. I want to use the same account from Stack Overflow. In other words, I want crypto.s.com to know that I am the same guy as on Stack Overflow.

On Stack Overflow, I use the Stack Exchange drop down in the navbar to add crypto.s.com to my communities, then navigate to crypto.s.com, and it still does not recognize me.

So, I click "log in". There is an option to "login with Stack Exchange", but it requires a email and password. I don't think I even have a Stack Exchange password. I just want a button or something that says "Ask stackexchange.com, they know who I am".

I suppose what I'm really after is this: one account page in stackexchange.com in which I add all my external OpenIds (like Google etc). So I can log into stackexchange.com using any of my external openids, and stackexchange.com to remember who I am. Then, when trying to log into new subsite (crypto.s.com for example), just OpenId to lookup from Stack Exchange who I am.

I don't want to have to duplicate the work I do in managing my list of external OpenIds on each sub site.

Is this possible?

Comment: Use the same OpenId you use on the other sites.

Comment: Oded, you are advising me to do exactly what I do now want to do. "duplicate the work I do in managing my list of external openids on each sub site".

Comment: @Jesse: No, once you connected an account, *all* OpenID accounts associated with it are managed centrally. The trick is to use an OpenID for new accounts you already used on the others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any 'disconnected' account is not using the same OpenID account(s) as the other, connected accounts.

To have your accounts across SE sites associated, use the same OpenID accounts. Once connected, the OpenID accounts you can log in with are managed centrally.

Say you have both a Google and a Yahoo account registered for Stack Overflow and ServerFault. Add *one* of those accounts to your Crypto.SE account too (click the *my logins* link on your account page), at which point your Crypto account will be associated with those on SO and SF, *and* you can now use both Google and Yahoo to log into Crypto.

The Stack Exchange login option is really *just another OpenID account*, albeit one that is a little better integration with the Stack Exchange network; you can sign up for such an account right here, you can change your password while on any Stack Exchange site, and logging in doesn't redirect to another site first.

If you add a Stack Exchange login, you can use it to log in to all your associated Stack Exchange accounts without having to add it manually to all those accounts. This applies to all OpenID accounts you add this way.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, makes sense.